# How to convert groups of columns into rows in Pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Say I have a DataFrame as the following:

| Name | Time worked in 1st hr | Time wasted in 1st hr | Time worked in 2nd hr | Time wasted in 2nd hr |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| foo | 45 | 15 | 40 | 20 |
| bar | 35 | 25 | 55 | 5 |
| baz | 50 | 10 | 45 | 15 |

I wish to use the melt on the 1st hour columns and 2nd hour columns to make it look like this:

| Name | Hour number | Time worked in the hr | Time wasted in the hr |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| foo | 1 | 45 | 15 |
| foo | 2 | 40 | 20 |
| bar | 1 | 35 | 25 |
| bar | 2 | 55 | 5 |
| baz | 1 | 50 | 10 |
| baz | 2 | 45 | 15 |

How would I group the "Time worked in 1st hr" and "Time wasted in 1st hr" together such that I can melt them both into the same row?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
df1 = df.set_index('Name')
df1.columns = df1.columns.str.split('in', expand=True)

df2 = (df1.stack()
          .sort_index(axis=1, ascending=False)
          .rename_axis(index=['Name', 'Hour number'])
          .add_suffix('in the hr')
          .reset_index()
      )

df2['Hour number'] = df2['Hour number'].str.extract(r'(\d+)')
```

**Result:**

```
print(df2)

  Name Hour number  Time worked in the hr  Time wasted in the hr
0  foo           1                     45                     15
1  foo           2                     40                     20
2  bar           1                     35                     25
3  bar           2                     55                      5
4  baz           1                     50                     10
5  baz           2                     45                     15
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm not sure what the last line is supposed to do, what is str.extract supposed to do in this case?

Comment: @crysoar  The last line is to extract the hour number from the text `1st`, `2nd`, etc.   If you run the codes above step by step without the last line, you will see the intermediate result of `Hour number` holding `1st hr`, `2nd hr`.   We need to clean up and get only the number.

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
import numpy as np
df = df.set_index('Name')
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([np.repeat([1,2], len(df.columns)//2), np.tile(['worked', 'wasted'], len(df.columns)//2)])
df.stack(level=0)
```

*NB. I couldn't test the code*

Answer (score 1):

You can do all the text processing within the columns before reshaping; the less number of rows to work on, the better/faster your code can be:

Set `Name` as index:

```
df = df.set_index('Name')
```

Extract the numbers, and set `expand=False`, so it stays as an index:

```
 numbers = df.columns.str.extract(r"(\d)", expand=False).rename("Hour Number")
```

Replace the numbers with `the`:

```
no_numbers = df.columns.str.replace("\d.{2}", "the", regex=True)
```

Create a MultiIndex column:

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([numbers, no_numbers])
```

Stack the columns and reset the index:

```
df.stack('Hour Number').reset_index()

  Name Hour Number  Time wasted in the hr  Time worked in the hr
0  foo           1                     15                     45
1  foo           2                     20                     40
2  bar           1                     25                     35
3  bar           2                      5                     55
4  baz           1                     10                     50
5  baz           2                     15                     45
```